# finding number of polynomials satisfying the above expression of $degree>=1$ and $f(x^2)=f(x)^2=f(f(x))$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Could you please help me to solve the question in the above title like how many polynomials satisfy the above expression,can you also guide a textbook for these type of questions

Thanks in advance

Comment: Writing thewe in terms of the roots of f might help​.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f(x)$ has degree $n$. Then $f(x^2)$ has degree $2n$, and $f(f(x))$ has degree $n^2$. Thus, $n=0$ or $n=2$. The $n=0$ case is trivial.

For the $n=2$ case, let $f(x) = ax^2+bx+c$. Then
$$f(x^2) =ax^4+bx^2+c$$
$$f(x)^2 = a^2x^4+2abx^3+(2ac+b^2)x^2+2bcx+c^2$$
Setting corresponding coefficients equal in the above,we see that $a=1$, $b=0$, $c=0$, and so $f(x)=x^2$. $f(x^2) = f(f(x))$, and so this is our only quadratic solution.